# How to update multiple rows in SQL using a dict?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sql-update

I have a huge dict of key/value pairs, something like

```
user_map = {
    ...
    "A123": "A734",
    "A342": "B322",
    ...
}
```

I have a table UserTable with two columns

> ```
> +-----+---------+
> | id  | user_id |
> +-----+---------+
> | 1   | A123    |
> | 2   | A372    |
> | ... | ...     |
> +-----+---------+
> ```

I want to query the UserTable, and update the user_id if present in keys of user_map to its corresponding value. For example, in the table above, A123 will be updated to A734.

I am trying to do it in a single query.

Comment: (1) I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  (2) There is no such thing as a "dict" in SQL, so presumably you are using some application language.  You should tag with that language.

Answer (score -1):

```
for key in dictW:
    x = dictW[key]
    print(key, x)
```

This look gives you key and value separately so you can use them in your SQL statement. This will iterate through your dictionary so you can get a list of keys and values separately for your SQL statement

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = value WHERE row = number
```

Comment: . . I didn't downvote this answer, but I don't think the OP wants to *write* separate update statements.  I think the OP wants python to generate the appropriate code.